# How to pass image URL in parameters to New?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, routes, paperclip

This is what I've tried:

**index**

```
<%= link_to new_inspiration_path(inspiration: {image: inspiration.image}) %> # user clicks this
```

**controller**

```
def new
  @inspiration = current_user.inspirations.build(inspiration_params)
end

def inspiration_params
  params.require(:inspiration).permit(:name, :image, :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size, :image_updated_at)
end
```

**server**

```
Started GET "/inspirations/new?inspiration_image=%2Fsystem%2Finspirations%2Fimages%2F000%2F000%2F069%2Foriginal%2Frule_1.jpg%3F1478260961" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-04 08:10:41 -0400
Processing by InspirationsController#new as */*
  Parameters: {"inspiration_image"=>"/system/inspirations/images/000/000/069/original/rule_1.jpg?1478260961"} # For example, this is the image url I'm trying to show in the _form
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 129]]
  Inspiration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "inspirations".* FROM "inspirations" WHERE "inspirations"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Completed 400 Bad Request in 6ms
```

**_form**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@inspiration, html: { data: { modal: true } }) do |f| %> 
  <%= image_tag @inspiration.image.url %> # doesn't show image, says "missing"
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

**model**

```
class Inspiration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :small => "150x150>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I get error: **ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/original/missing.png"):**

Comment: If you're using rails > 5, your models must inherit `ApplicationRecord`

Comment: @AkashAggarwal I'm using `4.2.0.rc3`

Comment: @AkashAggarwal no - you can set your records to inherit directly from `ActiveRecord::Base` in Rails 5 if you want. `ApplicationRecord` is just an empty class that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` - it also has nothing to do with a routing error.

Comment: @max I didn't say that the routing error was caused by the model thingy. It's just important to do that in rails 5 because `ApplicationRecord` is an abstract class and most gems use it to modify the code of `ActiveRecord::Base` in the respective model's context only, for example devise.